# Retrieving Page from HTTPS Website

Tags: ssl, https, security, html

I am registered user of a website that provides stock quotes values and I want to create a desktop application where in I will display the stock updates of a specific quotes.

For that, I need to parse a web page which is visible only when I login to the website. If I try to access that page, without logging in, it redirects me to the login page.

The Website does not provide any API for developing such a client application. Is there any way I can login to the website using the desktop client and thus access the required web page?

Regards,
TheLameProgrammer

Comment: Have you requested permission / a licence from the website so that you can do this? Having worked with teams providing stock quotes, and knowing how strongly they protect their intellectual property I'd be astonished if they'd allow this. Prepare for lawsuits if you do implement this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to first do a HTTP POST to the login page, store the cookies that come back, then pass these along with any furture request you make.

Same as the browser does.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this question is in earnest and not spam but the answer is no

Comment: But.. the answer isn't... oh, wait, are you trying to prevent someone from scraping pay-content?  In that case, it is no...

Comment: Lame down vote when I explained why I didn't think the question was in earnest from a person with 1 point reputation.

Comment: 'twasn't me, I promise.  I was trying to back you up if you were preventing commercial content scrape....